# Reason behind formation of Mach rings

Tags: jet-engine, supersonic, shock-waves

At night, some jet aircraft like Mirage 2000 leave a trail of discs behind in their jet, these are also known as [Mach rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond) or Mach diamonds.

How are they formed and what atmospheric conditions govern their formation?